# MDX tuple not returning correct value

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube

I have a test cube with one dimension and one fact table.

[image: Cube Dimension and Fact]

Superbill Key on Fact Superbill references the Primary Key on Dim Superbills.

On my Fact Superbill measure group I have several measures, including one which is a Fact Superbill Count. Based on this measure, I create a calculated member called Generated Superbills as follows:

```
([Measures].[Fact Superbill Count], [Dim Superbills].[Is Void].&[No])
```

On the cube browser I create the following query that returns only one SuperbillKey, including the Fact Superbill Count and Generated Superbills. The results show the correct value for Fact Superbill Count (which is one since I am only getting one Superbill), but Generated Superbills show 23.

[image: Cube Browser Query]

What am I doing wrong? Both should return 1.

Comment: how is this calculated? `[Measures].[Fact Superbill Count]`

Comment: `[Measures].[Fact Superbill Count]` is just a count of the Superbill Key on FactSuperbill.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it was not working, but I was able to find a solution for this. `Superbill Key` on DimSuperbills had a Key Value and a Name Value (the name value was not unique). I removed Name value and left only they key. I ran the MDX query after these changes and it worked.